# Can I Create a Boolean with a Negative Object in X3D?

Tags: java, x3d

I have two objects.  One represents a wall and one represents a door or window.  I have the dimensions of both.  If I was working in a 3D program like Cinema 4d, I would group the objects as a boolean and make the door/window a negative object.  Is there any way to do this in X3D?

Answer (score 0):

There is no boolean operator on models in X3D, however you could make a PROTO that modifies the coordinates of an existing model to fit to the desired size using a Script.

Otherwise, if your question is just about how to get your model exported from Cinema4D so that it looks the same: I never used C4D so I'm not sure what's the exact procedure, but in 3dsmax you would collapse the modifier stack to end up with a basic Mesh, then you would be able to export that.